# Loopback 4 - Get subcollection from Firestore

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, loopback

Loopback 4 has a community maintained connector for Firestore here: https://github.com/dyaa/loopback-connector-firestore

How do I get the the subcollection **houses** from the following collection:

```html
{
  village: {
    id: "yaOh(37Na",
    name: "Greenwich",
    houses: {
      house01: {
        address: "1st Street"
      },
      house02: {
        address: "2nd Street"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The following snippet returns only shallow results:

```html
const village = await this.villageRepository.findOne({where: {id: "yaOh(37Na"}});

console.log(village); // returns {id: "yaOh(37Na", name: "Greenwich"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Firestore reading from a collection, only reads the data from *that* collection and not from collections under it. There is no API that automatically reads data from subcollection too.

You'll have to execute a separate read operation for each subcollection that you want to get data from.

Comment: Reading subcollections are possible with a server-side query. Documentation can be found at the end of the page, here: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data

Comment: You can get a **list** of subcollections, but you can't read documents from them at the same time you read the village document.